# Commutator subgroup and subgroup generated by square.

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

While reading *Cours d'algèbre* by D. Perrin, I found the following claim:

> **Proposition.** If $G$ is a group, then $D(G)\subseteq G^2$, where $G^2$ is the subgroup generated by the squares of $G$.

I understand that it suffices to prove that for all $x,y\in G$, $[x,y]:=xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$ is a product of squares.

Equivalently, since $G^2$ is characteristic, hence normal, it suffices to establish that $G/G^2$ is abelian.

For now, none of my attempts have been fruitful. Any enlightenment will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Out of curiosity: is $D(G)$ a notation for the commutator subgroup?

Comment: @Student Yes, this is exactly what it is!

Comment: Oh, never saw that one before :)

Comment: For a direct proof, just observe that $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}=x^2(x^{-1}y)^2y^{-2}$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hint: prove that in a group in which every square is the identity, the group must be abelian. Then apply to $G/G^2$.  Note that $g^2=1$ is equivalent to $g=g^{-1}$.

Comment: I was just missing that in $G/G^2$ every element squared is the identity! Thank you for you guidance!

Comment: You are welcome!