# On the meaning of "$F^2$" in Robinson's Exercise 6.1.7.

Tags: group-theory, notation, free-groups

I am confused about some notation in **Exercise 6.1.7** of Robinson's, *"A Course in the Theory of Groups (Second Edition)"*.

Here is the exercise:

> **Exercise 6.1.7:** Let $F$ be a free group of finite rank $n$. Find the rank of $F^2$ as a free group.

### The Question:

> What does Robinson mean by "$F^2$"?

### Thoughts:

It cannot be the free product. That's covered in the next section of the book.

---

It cannot be the subgroup product

$$\begin{align}
F^2&=FF\\
&=\{ fg\mid f,g\in F\}\\
&=\{ h\mid h\in F\}\\
&=F
\end{align}$$

because that would be silly.

---

It cannot be the direct product. Otherwise, we would have, for example, via [this well-known result](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2376694/104041),

$$\begin{align}
F_2^2&=F_2\times F_2\\
&\cong\langle a,b\mid \rangle\times \langle x,y\mid \rangle\\
&\cong\langle a,b,x,y\mid ax=xa, ay=ya, bx=xb, by=yb\rangle,
\end{align}$$

which is not free.

---

Please help  :)

Comment: Could it be the set of words with an even number of letters?

Comment: I don't know, @RobertShore. You reminded me that $$F^2=\{ f^2\mid f\in F\}$$ could be an option.

Comment: @Shaun That's not a subgroup. It might be the subgroup generated by all squares $f^2$.

Comment: My guess is that Derek’s right. Googling finds there’s [at least one place](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2192244/commutator-subgroup-and-subgroup-generated-by-square) where that notation is used.

Comment: Assuming that $F^2 = \langle f^2 : f \in F \rangle$, you need to work out the index of $F^2$ in  $F$. Then you can calculate its rank using the index formula.